# convert date format

Tags: c#, winforms

how to convert : `7/30/2010 11:05:53 AM`

to : `30/07/2010`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert any type of date to dd/mm/yyyy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248561/how-to-convert-any-type-of-date-to-dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DateTime temp = DateTime.Parse("7/30/2010 11:05:53 AM");

string converted = temp.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

-- Using Try Parse ---

```
// Try Parse is better because if the format is invalid an exception is not thrown.
DateTime temp;

string converted = string.Empty;

if (DateTime.TryParse("7/30/2010 11:05:53 AM", out temp))
{
    // True means Date was converted properly
    converted = temp.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
else
{
    converted = "ERROR in PARSING";
}
```

Comment: Doesn't anyone here use TryParse?

Comment: @fletcher ask and you shall receive.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive you can use `DateTime.Parse("7/30/2010 11:05:53 AM").ToShortDate()` (depending on the culture)